# How to run twice soap request in SoapUI using threads?

Tags: multithreading, groovy, soapui

In SoapUI I prepared TestCase (Options - generate data) consisting of three test steps:

1. Properties
2. Groovy Script
3. Generate (disabled)

In this test I want to run third step only two times in the same time (that's why I don't use LoadTest) and verify obtained results - they should be different. For this, I wrote a simple script which is presented below.

```
def testData = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties");

class MyThread extends Thread {
def i;
def testData;

MyThread(def i, def testData) {
    this.i = i;
    this.testData = testData;
}

 void run() {
    generateData();     
}

void generateData() {
    def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);

    def testCaseStep = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["Options - generate data"];
    def soapStep = testCaseStep.testSteps["Generate"];

    soapStep.run(testRunner, context);
    def xmlResponse = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Generate#response")
    def responseData = xmlResponse.getNodeValues("//ns2:getResponse/ns2:response");

    def row = "row" + this.i;

    this.testData.setPropertyValue(row, responseData.toString());
}
}

MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(0, testData);
MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(1, testData);

thread1.start();
thread2.start();

while ((thread1.isAlive() &&  thread2.isAlive())) {
    def data1 = testData.getPropertyValue("row0");
    def data2 = testData.getPropertyValue("row1");
    assert data1 != data2;
    }
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work correctly - I don't have any error, but SOAP requests don't start, new variables are not created and assertion is failed.

Could you tell me what is necessary to obtain good result of this test?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things which are fixed in the code:

- `context` is used in the **method** and is not available
- threads to be joined
- while getting the data, you need the object reference

Fixed code:

```
def testData = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")

class MyThread extends Thread {
    def threadId
    def testData
    def context

    MyThread(def i, def testData, def context) {
            threadId = i
            this.testData = testData
            this.context = context
    }

    void run() {
            generateData()
    }

    void generateData() {
        def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
        def soapStep = context.testCase.testSteps["Generate"]
        soapStep.run(context.testRunner, context)
        def xmlResponse = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Generate#response")
        def responseData = xmlResponse.getNodeValues("//ns2:getResponse/ns2:response")    
        testData.setPropertyValue("row${threadId}" as String, responseData.toString())
    }
}

MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(0, testData, context)
MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(1, testData, context)

thread1.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.start()
thread2.join()

while ((thread1.isAlive() &&  thread2.isAlive())) {
    def data1 = thread1.testData.getPropertyValue(thread1.threadId)
    def data2 = thread2.testData.getPropertyValue(thread2.threadId)
    assert data1 != data2
}
```